# Configure logging retention policy for Apache airflow

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I could not find in Airflow docs how to set up the retention policy I need.
Currently, all airflow logs have to be manually deleted, else they will be kept forever on our servers...  Not the best way to go.

I wish to create global logs configurations for all the different logs I have.

How and where do I configure:

1. Number of days to keep
2. Max file size

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same situation yesterday, the solution for me was to use a DAG that handles all the log cleanup and schedule it as any other DAG.

Check this [repo](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/log-cleanup), you will find a step-by-step guide on how to set it up. Basically what you will achieve is to delete files located on  `airflow-home/log/` and `airflow-home/log/scheduler` based on a given period defined on a `Variable`. The DAG dynamically creates one task for each directory targeted for deletion based on your previous definition.

In my case, the only modification I made to the original DAG was to allow deletion only to the *scheduler* folder by replacing the initial value of `DIRECTORIES_TO_DELETE`. All credits to the creators! works very well out of the box, and it's easy to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from apache-airflow 2.6.0 , you can set the below value in airflow.cfg in the logging section .

```
delete_local_logs = True
```

For this to work , you should enable remote logging , which pushes the log files to a remote S3 bucket or something similar .Airflow automatically pushes the logs to the configured remote folder and deletes the local files. You can set a BucketLifecycleConfiguration on the S3 bucket based on your log retention period to delete the old log files in the bucket automatically .

Go through the logging documentation from airflow docs for more information:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.0/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html