# Overtime airflow creates huge amount of logs. I want to know if airflow logs can be removed based on how old it's via airflow inbuild configurations

Tags: logging, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Overtime airflow creates huge amount of logs. I want to know if airflow logs can be removed based on how old it is via airflow inbuild configurations.
Though I did came across building dags to cleanup the logs as in below.

[Configure logging retention policy for Apache airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580751/configure-logging-retention-policy-for-apa)

I'm looking for solutions that can be configured via airflow.cfg

If such solution do not exist, please let me know if simply deleting the files from AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/ based on the date will mess up airflow logging. Will it have dangling file pointers that shows the log exist, but it actually got deleted manually without airflow's intervention. If so, will it have any impact?? What all should we consider while creating a custom script to clean up such folders via a dag??
If options are not available via airflow.cfg. I want to know the best practices on building a custom dag that removes these airflow generated log and also any possible way I can reduce the size of log?

I checked airflow documentation for 2.6.1 and found it allows log deletion for remote logging via airflow.cfg. Other than that i Couldn't find anything. The airflow I'm using have only local logging system.

Answer (score 0):

#### Purge your logs on a regular basis

As stated in [Best Practices | Metadata DB maintenance](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#metadata-db-maintenance),

> You can use the Airflow CLI to purge old data with the command airflow db clean.

Here is the link to `db clean` [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/usage-cli.html#purge-history-from-metadata-database) about it.

> It’s strongly recommended that you backup the metadata database before running the db clean command.

#### Some people automatize it

You should also have a look at teamclairvoyant's [airflow maintenance DAGs](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags)

They developed [a specific DAG for cleaning logs](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/log-cleanup) with a nice README.

> A maintenance workflow that you can deploy into Airflow to periodically clean out the task logs to avoid those getting too big.

Don't forget to set parameters according to your needs:

- `airflow_log_cleanup__max_log_age_in_days`
- `airflow_log_cleanup__enable_delete_child_log`